# Excel: change VBA action frome same sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, document, generate

As I'm trying my first Excel with macro's I could really use some help. I'm not a programmer but I can edit some code very well.

My goal is to generate some different word documents by the click of a button. The excel file is a list with achievements of students. The results are listed in the different word documents. It's kind of a mail merge but without opening Word.

The code I have now is for a button in the same sheet to generate those word documents. Now I changed the whole excel file...and I'm lost with the VBA.
I know it has something to do with:

```
Sub Selecteren_Cijferlijst()

' Selecteren_Cijferlijst Macro
    Sheets("Cijferlijst").Select

End Sub
```

The code I got from a kind user on a forum is this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Vooraanmelding()

Dim lonLaatsteRij As Long
Dim rngData As Range
Dim strGeboortedatum As String, strStudentnummer As String, strVoornaam As String, strAchternaam As String, strAdres As String, strPostcode As String, strWoonplaats As String, strTelefoon As String, strEmail As String, strCrebo As String, strKlas As String, strProfiel As String, strSlber As String
Dim c As Range

With ActiveSheet
'bepaal de onderste rij van het actieve excel-werkblad
lonLaatsteRij = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'stel bereik in
Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lonLaatsteRij, 1))
End With

For Each c In rngData
c.Select
strGeboortedatum = c.Offset(0, 7).Value
strStudentnummer = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
strVoornaam = c.Value
strAchternaam = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
strAdres = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
strPostcode = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
strWoonplaats = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
strTelefoon = c.Offset(0, 8).Value
strEmail = c.Offset(0, 9).Value
strCrebo = c.Offset(0, 10).Value
strKlas = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
strProfiel = c.Offset(0, 11).Value
strSlber = c.Offset(0, 12).Value
Call maakWordDocument(strGeboortedatum, strStudentnummer, strVoornaam, 
strAchternaam, strAdres, strPostcode, strWoonplaats, strTelefoon, strEmail, 
strCrebo, strKlas, strProfiel, strSlber)
Next c

End Sub

Private Sub maakWordDocument(strGeboortedatum As String, strStudentnummer As String, strVoornaam As String, strAchternaam As String, strAdres As String, strPostcode As String, strWoonplaats As String, strTelefoon As String, strEmail As String, strCrebo As String, strKlas As String, strProfiel As String, strSlber As String)

'maak een verwijzing naar de Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library!!

Dim wordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next

'kijk of word al open staat
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
'open word
If wordApp Is Nothing Then
  'If Not open, open Word Application
  Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
'toon word (of niet, dan op false)
wordApp.Visible = False
'open het 'bron'-bestand
Set WordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "Vooraanmelding\Vooraanmelding.docx")

'bladwijzers invullen
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "geboortedatum", strGeboortedatum)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "studentnummer", strStudentnummer)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "voornaam", strVoornaam)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "achternaam", strAchternaam)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "adres", strAdres)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "postcode", strPostcode)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "woonplaats", strWoonplaats)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "telefoon", strTelefoon)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "email", strEmail)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "crebo", strCrebo)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "klas", strKlas)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "profiel", strProfiel)
Call InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp, "slber", strSlber)

'bestand opslaan en alles netjes afsluiten
wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
WordDoc.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "Vooraanmelding\Vooraanmelding " & strVoornaam & Space(1) & strAchternaam, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
WordDoc.Close
wordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set wordApp = Nothing
wordApp.DisplayAlerts = True

On Error GoTo 0


End Sub


 Sub InvullenBladwijzer(wordApp As Object, strBladwijzer As String, strTekst As String)

'tekst invullen in relevante strBladwijzer
wordApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=strBladwijzer
wordApp.Selection.TypeText strTekst

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

This code is what someone gave me, it was a quick 'n' dirty solution for the file I had. Now I changed the setup of my excel so my colleagues also can work with it. That's why I decided to put all buttons on a separate sheet.

Comment: what is the sheet name where you get all of your values? (where is `rngData`?)

Comment: `With ActiveSheet` >> `With Sheets("Cijferlijst")`

Comment: @urdearboy The sheet all values are from is called Cijferlijst. In the old file it used to have the buttons and all the values on the same sheet. Now I'm trying to change the whole file so the buttons have their own sheet. Just to have everything clear for my colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to directly qualify your range `rngData` with a sheet and not rely on `ActiveSheet`.

Delete first sub and link buttons to `Sub Vooraanmelding`

```
With Sheets("Cijferlijst")
    lonLaatsteRij = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lonLaatsteRij, 1))
End With
```

Comment: I Changed it. Now VBA gives an error in the next statement:
For Each c In rngData
c.Select

This c.Select isn't right?

Comment: Delete `c.Select`

Comment: You do not need to `Select` a cell to know its location, change, copy, or delete it when using VBA.

Comment: I did delete it. Now the private sub gives an error: a variable is not defined.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? As I don't have a lot of knowledge about VBA I have no idea how or where to put this.

Comment: What line is highlighted? The variable needs to be defined (`Dim ? as ?`) @DavidZemens OP already has option explicit which is why he is getting the error.

Comment: The highlighted line is the line that starts with "Private Sub maakWordDocument".

Comment: It should highlight the offending variable in blue, like screenshot here: https://imgur.com/gTCn3Zg

Comment: Obvious culprit, unless you have reference to Microsoft Word, would be `wdFormatDocument` which is a Word constant that is not normally available in Excel unless you declare it yourself or add a project reference to Word.

Comment: @DavidZemens: My bad, I thought the yellow line was higlighted, but that is probably the step VBA is blocked.

The highlighted word is indeed wdFormatDocument, furter in the WordDoc.SaveAs line.

Comment: I Got it sorted out, kind of...

These lines are now outcommented:
   ** 'wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'On Error GoTo 0**

And **Set wordApp = GetObject("", "Word.Application")** has now 2 double brackets before "Word.Application"

The VBA runs like I want it to run, without errors.

Needless to say: the code is a "quick 'n' dirty" one, I have totally no clue on how to get this a quality code.

Thanks for helping out.